# ReactiveExtension calling async code on demand

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I have a property `IObservable<ServiceStatus>` that should be updated on demand by using a method that uses the async pattern. If anything error occurred,  it should be swallowed. `statusNeedToBeUpdated` is an observable that informs me, when my Property  should be updated. Basically the following code does what needs to be done:

```
Status = statusNeedToBeUpdated
    .Select(_ => {
        try {
            var task = client.ServiceStatus.GetAsync();
            task.Wait();
            return task.Result;
        }
        catch (Exception) {
            return null;
        }
    })
    .Where(status => status != null);
```

I think there should be a more advanced way to handle the async call to client.ServiceStatus: I came up with this:

```
Status = statusNeedToBeUpdated
    .Select(async _ => await client.ServiceStatus.GetAsync())
    .Catch(Observable.Return(Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> (ServiceStatus)null)))
    .Where(task => task.Result != null)
    .Select(task => task.Result);
```

This solution is better, but I don't like to start a new Task that simply returns null.
Does anybody know a better solution.

Comment: So you want to subscribe to one observable, do something and publish the result of that something. Instead of this code, subscribe to `statusNeedToBeUpdated` and replace `Status` with a [Subject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242970(v=vs.103).aspx) on which you can post the result with OnNext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you need this query:

```
Status =
    statusNeedToBeUpdated
        .SelectMany(_ =>
            Observable
                .FromAsync(() => client.ServiceStatus.GetAsync())
                .Retry());
```

This will retry anytime `GetAsync` throws an error and avoids the need to return dummy values or tasks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Task<ServiceStatus>.FromResult(null)` which will return an already completed task rather than create a new one.

But you may also be able to use `Observable.FromAsync` to simplify it.

```
Status = statusNeedToBeUpdated
   .Select(_ => Observable.FromAsync<ServiceStatus>(async () => await client.ServiceStatus.GetAsync())
   .SelectMany(s=> s);
```